# Отбрасывание "сложных" выражений в SymPy

Tags: python-3.5, sympy

Пишу что-то в духе калькулятора. На вход поступает строка с выражением. Проблема в том, что она может быть очень сложной для вычисления(ответ будет получаться ооочень долго, для меня это критично). Если такое выражение поступает на вход, необходимо сообщить, что оно не может быть обработано. Думал сделать по количеству символов, но выражение 12**123456 не очень длинное, но обрабатываться будет долго. Мб как-нибудь это по таймеру сделать?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period)

Comment: Можно [самостоятельно ввод для вашего случая попробовать распарсить](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2371436/4279). В общем случае, sympy может вызвать долгую C функцию, не отпустив GIL, поэтому единственный надёжный метод реализации timeout это использование внешнего процесса (`multiprocessing`, `subprocess`). Опишите подробнее, какой входной формат, на каких системах программа будет запускаться.

Comment: Может, входные выражения разбирать [по сложности](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)?